# Laravel never forget an item from session

Tags: php, session, laravel, laravel-5

I push an array into Laravel session:

```
  "accountConfirm" => array:1 [
    0 => array:2 [
      "table" => "teacher"
      "id" => 37
    ]
  ]
```

When I call to `Session::flush()` or `Session::forget('accountConfirm')` and in below line make the test

```
if ( Session::has('accountConfirm') ) 
{
  // false
}
```

But after, without the remove functions (flush, forget) when I make the same test:

```
if ( Session::has('accountConfirm') ) 
{
  // true
}
```

To make sure, I'm not more pushing this item.

Why this occurs?

Comment: I'm a bit confused, if you don't remove the session why are you expecting that it should of been removed? Does each *test* add the `accountConfirm` in the session, or are you doing this once and expecting to be gone after the removal of the item?

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek now i'm also confused. If call `Session::forget('accountConfirm')` i expected that this item should be removed from `Session` array and no more accessible. This is a wrong?

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek because it is data that I want do not continue in the session

Comment: If you use `Session::forget('accountConfirm')` accountConfirm will no longer exist in the session. What is the issue?

Comment: @mdamia yes, the problem is after `Session::forget('accountConfirm')` accountConfirm persist in the session

Answer (score -1):

copy and past this in you route and navigate to each url to see the result.

```
Route::get('/session/set',function(){
  Session::put('name','John');
  if (Session::has('name')){
    echo Session::get('name');
  }
});

Route::get('/session/forget/',function(){
  Session::forget('name');
  if (Session::has('name')){
    echo Session::get('name');
  }else{
    echo 'Name is not set';
  }
});
```